# Power Query: Is there a way to have the average of grades of every student with multiple grades?

Tags: powerquery

I have a table with Student ID's (1-11) and they repeat 5 times, each of the students has 5 grades in 3 subjects. My assignment is to create a 3 new columns in the table with the average of every student in those 3 subjects. My problem is that I don't know how to do such a thing, as my professor asked the class to do this in this very weird way, which is making it hard to figure out how to do it.

[image]

As the image shows, it's a pretty weird setup for the table.
My question is as I described it before. I need to make 3 new columns with the average of every student, their 5 grades for each of the  subjects.

Comment: To me it looks like you need a secondary table with a groupby and a join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group a copy of the table by ID and average the columns with grades and join it with the original table.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSAWNjpVgdCM8IiE3gPGMgNgXzjMAsHSULOM8MiC3hPHOQSQZKsbEA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [id = _t, gradeA = _t, gradeB = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"id", Int64.Type}, {"gradeA", Int64.Type}, {"gradeB", Int64.Type}}),
    Buffer1 = Table.Buffer(#"Changed Type"),
    grouped = 
        let
            sourceGroup = Buffer1,
            grouped = Table.Group(sourceGroup,"id",{{"AVGgradeA", each List.Average([gradeA]), type nullable number}, {"AVGgradeB", each List.Average([gradeB]), type nullable number}})
        in
            grouped,
    #"join" = Table.Join(Buffer1,"id",grouped,"id")
in
    #"join"
```